# Multipurpose home server/NAS memory requirements

Tags: memory, nas, zfs, nextcloud

I'm building a NAS for my home & home office network.  The NAS has 4TB of data on it (ZFS RAID1) and 8 gigs of ECC memory.   The CPU is an E3-1230 v3.  I'll be running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on the server and VM.   My home network will support 4 laptops, 6 android cellphones, 2 TV's connected via WIFI and Gigabit ethernet.

I'm planning on setting up a KVM VM to sandbox "home" activities - these will be a Nextcloud server, DNLA media player, Photo and document store and SMB server.

On the VM host I'll be running some OpenVPN clients and possibly a server, doing backups and running DRBD for my work Laptop.

Can anyone advise -

- How much RAM do I need to allocate to the Family VM ?  (It will have about TB of storage available to it - a few small files, lots of photos and videos.
- What is the most practical way to provide disk for the Family VM ?  Should I create a ZVOL (block device) for its exclusive use, use NFS or p9_virtio ?  (I've never used VirtFS on KVM)

Comment: You've left out way too many details to get an accurate answer. What are your hard drives?  What disk controller?  What are your data access pattern(s)?  What are your bandwidth and latency requirements?  Are you expecting to support streaming three or four HD or even 4K videos at one time, for example?  That usage pattern would make the ZFS ARC size pretty irrelevant.  Other usage patterns could benefit from a huge ZFS ARC.  And even if you do get all those requirement details specified, you're likely basing them on something that's going to change soon anyway. Plan to add more RAM later.

Comment: Hard drives are 2xNAS SATA 4tb disks (sorry, I see what I wrote us misleading in q - not 4tb of files) + 2xssd which have mirrored zil and L2ARC.  Access patterns will be mainly write for backups which are local and over net, and fairly even read-write for other data. No DEDUP .  Most video will be streamed at less then 1gigabyte per hour, with no more then 3 streams. That equates to a paltry 7 megabit/sec. The usage patterns is not going to change soon.